# Choosing SQL Server version for new project

Tags: .net, sql-server

I've been developing projects using SQL Server Express 2008 R2 for a while because it's free.  It's been used for development and production.  I'm on a project now where I can choose the version to be used on the server for production.  If SQL Server 2014 is used on the production server can I development on my machine by using SQL Server Express 2014 and have it be compatible with the full version on the server?  I don't have an MSDN subscription so I can't get the full version for my machine.

Comment: Express Version is only there for Testing SQL Server, You should be using SQL Server Developer Edition to develop applications ask your client to get the Edition which suits their business requirements best. 

You and your client both should have a good look at [`Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2014`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)

You go for Developer's Edition and ask your client to decide after reading this document what version they should get, you are talking about many thousands of dollars, so be careful with what you suggest.

Comment: @M.Ali That's just not true. Express Edition is licensed for production use, as long as your database fits within the size limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Sql Server 2014 Express to develop for Sql Server 2014 Standard or Sql Server 2014 Enterprise.

Note that Sql Server 2014 Express won't let you use any of the features in Sql Server Enterprise Edition, though. If you want any of those features, you'll also want Sql Server Developer Edition (only costs about $50).  However, if your organization has several applications that run on Sql Server, or large (100GB+) databases in Sql Server, they may still get value from choosing Enterprise Edition, even if you only have Express Edition to develop with.